# Dojo or flex with Grails?

Tags: apache-flex, grails, dojo

I plan to build a database management system using Grails as the main framework.  On the client side, I'm thinking whether to use dojo or flex to make a nice front end.

Could some experts here enlighten me on the pros and cons of choosing either, or both?

or any other options?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using Dojo in a project and even brought a few books. And while Dojo Looks good I found that JQuery and JQuery-UI was a lot lighter and worked faster.

This is just my opinion and it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

From the description of the flex plugin at http://www.grails.org/Flex+Plugin
"This plugin was created as an experiment to prove that it's possible to communicate from Flex to Grails services without any configuration in Flex. There
is no plan to add functionality or whatsoever. It's not sure if the plugin works in production mode as it is only tested in development mode. This plugin
can be seen as an example on how to integrate Flex and Grails with Convention over Configuration in mind."

There is no scaffolding generation for flex, see [this bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS-225)

Another disadvantage of Flex is its lack of accessibility for screen reader users with the default configuration. There is some work being done to address this but it isn't publically available yet.

I don't have experience with DOJO but according to [this link](http://www.grails.org/Ajax) if you use the standard Grails Ajax tags you should be able to switch libraries with out to much trouble and won't be tied to Dojo. For fancy UI stuff such as tabbed interfaces and data tables I've found [GrailsUI](http://grails.org/plugin/grails-ui) works well for me. A demo project showing its features can be found at http://code.google.com/p/guidemo/ although you'll have to check the code out to run it.

Answer (score 0):

I am developing an information-management application with Dojo 1.9.2 and Grails 2.3.9 (lots of simle/complex forms, listing screens...etc). The application has a single-page interface as well (a workspace) which was the primary reason for a heavy JavaScript library.

Overall, Dojo is fairly suitable for this kind of workload and I haven't bumped into any show-stoppers yet.

I needed to do a lot of work on integrating the Dojox DataGrid into the application (extending QueryReadStore to fit with Grails better...etc) and a set of custom widget extensions (e.g. a real, working AutoComplete).

After this larger, initial integration work is done, you can expect a fairly smooth ride.